# Popup is not working in Flutter Web VIew package

Tags: flutter, razorpay, flutterwebviewplugin

I am using 'flutter_webview' package for payment the web view working fine. but on payment its open new popup, that popup is working in other external browser but not in mobile view.

please guide me to handle the popup in webview.

```
 Expanded(
              child: WebView(
                debuggingEnabled: true,
                initialUrl: paymentUrl,
                allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _controller = webViewController;
                },
                onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError webviewerrr) {
                  print("Handle your Error Page here");
                },
                javascriptChannels: Set.from([
                  JavascriptChannel(
                    name: 'Alert',
                    onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
                      // alert message = Test alert Message
                      print(message.message);
                      // TODO popup
                    },
                  )
                ]),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Are you not getting an error message?

Comment: no i am not getting any error message. actually only the popup is not showing. rest everything is works fine.

Comment: Hey did you find a solution for this?

Comment: In my case rather then going razor pay with webview url from backend i suppose to do razor pay integration from front end. hence popup from webview is handled internally by razor pay package.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution, while using the razor pay we have to integrate [razorpay_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/razorpay_flutter) package instead of going with the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)